# How can I get the number of availableProcessors in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I would like to get the number of availableProcessors from with my Ant build script (i.e. value that is returned from Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors().  Is there an existing property that contains this value or do I have to write a custom ant task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[write your custom ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html), is simple as write a class

Comment: there's a small problem with this approach. The host that you use to build your service might be different than the host in which your service will run..... am I right? @dfa

Answer (score 4):

[This post by Ilia Chemodanov](http://www.iliachemodanov.ru/en/blog-en/15-tools/ant/48-get-number-of-processors-in-ant-en) explains two solutions nicely.

If you don't want to compile and import a Java class you can **do it in pure ant:** (though it is pretty hacky)

```
<target name="get-cores">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <!-- support for Windows -->
    <condition property="cores.count" value="${env.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}">
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>
    <!-- support for Linux and Solaris (package SUNWgnu-coreutils is required) -->
    <exec executable="nproc" outputproperty="cores.count" os="Linux,SunOS,Solaris">
        <arg value="--all"/>
    </exec>
    <!-- support for Mac OS X -->
    <exec executable="sysctl" outputproperty="cores.count" os="Mac OS X">
        <arg value="-n"/>
        <arg value="hw.ncpu"/>
    </exec>
    <echo message="Number of cores: ${cores.count}"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare this in your build:

```
<property runtime="runtime"/>
```

You get the number of processors with the property `${runtime.availableProcessors}`.

This requires Ant 1.9.12+ or Ant 1.10.4+

Answer (score -1):

The JVM does not provide such a property and neither does ant. Instead of writing a custom task you could do one of the following:

1. Write a Java class that prints the number of processors to standard output. Use the java task with the outputproperty attribute to set the value to a property for use in ant.
2. If you are only ever building one a single platform use the exec task to call something native that prints the number of processors to standard output. As above use the outputproperty attribute to set the value to a property for use in ant.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() is provided by the JVM

Comment: A method call is not a property, hence you need code to get to it.

Answer (score -1):

Like @dfa mentioned, writing your [own custom task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html) it's a good option.

However, if the host that builds your service is different from the host running it, then the number of cores will differ (you will get the number of available processors of the host that build your service).

If you DON'T want that, then you can just use a small shell script inside your build script, something like this (for UNIX like OSs):

```
$(/usr/bin/nproc --all)
```

I'd check if the command exists first, `if(type /usr/bin/nproc)`.... but that depends on how you want to implement it.

Answer (score -2):

I never heard about such a property, thus I think you should write your custom task.

Manu